# Passphrase during boot

Tags: partitioning, lvm, luks

Jus installed ubuntu on my Asus laptop, with 256 sad HD.
It demands a passphrase with the following message:

```
Please unlock disk sda3_crypt
```

My research discovered that my whole HD is encrypted, it's called LUKS or something. I know how to enable it, but how do I disable?
I just installed the OS, so reinstalling is an option
Thanks in advance, Gal.

Answer (score 3):

Reinstalling is probably the easiest way to get a system that is not encrypted.

You select it at the installer's partitioning page, 'Installation type'. Select the option you want

- either an 'automatic' alternative
- or the manual partitioning, 'Something else'

You should avoid the alternative LVM with encryption, 'Encrypt the new Ubuntu installation for security'.

Comment: Yeah I did that, but couldn't find how I actually delete the problematic portion and avoid the issue

Comment: @Chicko, It should work, if you select 'Erase Ubuntu ... and reinstall' (easy), or 'Something else' and edit the partitions manually (remove and create new partitions, more flexible but also more difficult).

Comment: I did that 2 times, once with "Erase disk..." and once with "something else". Problem returned. Is there anything specific that should be done in the partition manager?

Comment: Erase disk *should* erase all partitions and let the installer start from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out I'm not the best at reading. Just unmarked a checkbox. My bad...